# How to get click and another signals from insensitive widget?

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to get signal from insensitived widget. but when widget is insensitived with `widget.set_sensitive(False)` code line, singals of this widget not work. how can I ensure work the signals of the insensitive widgets ?

example

```
w = Gtk.Button("example")
w.set_sensitive(False)
w.connect("button-press-event", do_anything) # not work
```

I only want to freeze the widgets. but widgets completely not working with this way.

Comment: You can learn a lot of things by using [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pack the button in a EventBox.

```
e_b = Gtk.Eventbox()
button = Gtk.Button()
e_b.add(button)
e_b.set_above_child(True) #necessary for event handling
e_b.connect("button-press-event", do_anything)
```

However, it makes me wonder what you are trying to do. See @JoseFonte answer.

Comment: I just tried wrapping an insensitive button on a EventBox before answering :) Won't work. Well just noticed the set_above_child method. Let me check

Comment: @JoséFonte And I tried it too and it worked !? Did you remember to set the event handling *above* the child?

Comment: @JoséFonte I do wonder what this guy is doing. See some of his other questions.

Comment: indeed xD. This may be an answer to his previous question too which, by the case, is was planning to complement.. The detail of set_above_child (True) does the trick so i've upvoted it.

Comment: @Nomad Now could I ask you what you are doing? It must be something strange and it makes me very, very curious.

Comment: @theGtknerd, I am working on a project DailyWorkReporter. I can post my code about this to you when I finished. How can I post to you.

Comment: You could host it on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/).

Comment: @theGtknerd, I got it.
oh no. there is a new problem. I don't understand why gtk makes a new problem every time do ?. perhaps I chose wrong gui library.  I only wanted to make a new flowbox that focuses to any child automaticilly when any child is clilcked. but this flowbox do not automaticilly focus when the flowboxchilds clicked. for the focus to child, we have to click edges of child. why it not focus to any child when we clicked on everywhere of child ?. this is soo nonsense.

Comment: @Nomad Please post a new question. Remember to provide code that shows what is wrong.

Comment: @theGtknerd, I posted you can see

Comment: @Nomad I learned Gtk by using Anjuta. You can install Anjuta with Synaptic or your usual software installer on any Linux OS. This makes learning Gtk and Python a lot easier and faster.

Comment: @theGtknerd, anjuta not contain's any pygtk tutorial. I wanted to know where you learn gtk did ?. Universty ?, book ?, net ?

Comment: @Nomad I did not read tutorials. I opened a pygtk project in Anjuta and put buttons in a window, then boxes, eventboxes, frames, scrolled windows, treeviews, entries, radiobuttons, etc. Finally I figured out how Gtk things work.

Answer (score 1):

That is the meaning of the widgets not being sensitive. If so they won't emit signals to events and you won't be able to interact with them.

There are some situations where you want the widgets to be insensitive, for example, imagine a "Login" button in a authentication dialog but you only want to allow the login if both Username and Password are not empty. Then you can check the entries content and if none is empty then set the "Login" to be sensitive.

From the Python API - [Gtk.Widget set_sensitive](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_sensitive) method:

> Sets the sensitivity of a widget. A widget is sensitive if the user
>   can interact with it. Insensitive widgets are “grayed out” and the
>   user can’t interact with them. Insensitive widgets are known as
>   “inactive”, “disabled”, or “ghosted” in some other toolkits.